# Syle XUL scrollbar

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I want to change the style of a scrollbar to something other than the native scrollbar, so my UI stays the same across platforms.

Take for example, this xul element:

```
<richlistbox class="testRLB" height = "100px">
    <richlistitem ><listcell label="bla"/></richlistitem>
    <richlistitem ><listcell label="bla"/></richlistitem>
    <richlistitem ><listcell label="bla"/></richlistitem>
    <richlistitem ><listcell label="bla"/></richlistitem>
    <richlistitem ><listcell label="bla"/></richlistitem>
    <richlistitem ><listcell label="bla"/></richlistitem>
    <richlistitem ><listcell label="bla"/></richlistitem>
    <richlistitem ><listcell label="bla"/></richlistitem>
</richlistbox>`
```

Produced this:

[image]

I opened DOM Inspector and looked for the scrollbar:

[image]

Then i tried adding the styles:

```
.testRLB scrollbar {
    -moz-appearance: none !important;
    background-color: red !important;
    border: 1px solid green !important;
}

.testRLB scrollbar scrollbarbutton {
    -moz-appearance: none !important;
    background-color: blue !important;
    border: 1px solid yellow !important;
}
```

But nothing happened. Anyone has any idea if it is possible to do this, and if so, how?

Comment: I don't think you can style XBL "anonymous" child elements that way. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/XBL_bindings